# Fail to insert data(MS Access) into MS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I'm having trouble with my school work. Teacher want us to learn to collect data captured in an input form, package the form data in a Hashtable and use a prepared statement to insert the data in a database.

No matter what I do I'm still getting this error message : "An error occured. The record wasn't inserted."

Please help me

```
Option Explicit On  
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

 Public Class frmProduct
 Public Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ProcurementDB.accdb"

Private Sub frmProduct_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click

    Dim oConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING)

    Try
        Debug.Print("Connection string: " & oConnection.ConnectionString)

        oConnection.Open()
        Dim oCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        oCommand.Connection = oConnection

        Dim htData As Hashtable = New Hashtable
        htData("ProductName") = txtName.Text
        htData("ProductDescription") = txtDescription.Text
        htData("Category") = txtCategory.Text
        htData("ReorderLevel") = txtReorderLevel.Text
        htData("LeadTime") = txtLeadTime.Text
        If chkDiscontinued.Checked = True Then
            htData("Discontinued") = 1
        Else
            htData("Discontinued") = 0
        End If
        htData("UnitPrice") = txtUnitPrice.Text

        oCommand.CommandText = _
           "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_description, category, reorder_level, lead_time, discontinued, unit_price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

        oCommand.Parameters.Add("ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("ProductDescription", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("Category", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("ReorderLevel", OleDbType.Integer, 4)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("LeadTime", OleDbType.VarChar, 255)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("Discontinued", OleDbType.Integer, 1)
        oCommand.Parameters.Add("UnitPrice", OleDbType.Double, 8)

        oCommand.Parameters("ProductName").Value = CStr(htData("ProductName"))
        oCommand.Parameters("ProductDescription").Value = CStr(htData("ProductDescription"))
        oCommand.Parameters("Category").Value = CStr(htData("Category"))
        oCommand.Parameters("ReorderLevel").Value = CInt(htData("ReorderLevel"))
        oCommand.Parameters("LeadTime").Value = CStr(htData("LeadTime"))
        oCommand.Parameters("Discontinued").Value = CInt(htData("Discontinued"))
        oCommand.Parameters("UnitPrice").Value = CDbl(htData("UnitPrice"))

        oCommand.Prepare()

        Debug.Print("SQL: " & oCommand.CommandText)

        oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Debug.Print("The record was inserted.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
        MsgBox("An error occured. The record wasn't inserted.")
    Finally
        oConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You omitted the most relevant parts: the output of `Debug.Print("SQL: " & oCommand.CommandText)` and `Debug.Print("ERROR: " & ex.Message)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. What should I do to correct it??
I wrote the exact same code from my lecture file but I just don't know why mine is not working. Is it because I left the database empty?

Comment: You have a line `Debug.Print("ERROR: " & ex.Message)` in your code. We need the output of this, from the Debug window / Immediate window. If you can't find it, change `Debug.Print` to `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the time field, thus this correction:

```
oCommand.Parameters("LeadTime").Value = CDate(htData("LeadTime"))
```